# how to send multipart/form-data via InvokeHttp NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi, databricks, kylo

I have a 3rd party REST, which I am successfully able to call like this using CURL (shell). This API return JSON. I tried calling same API, by changing content type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` but it doesn't work. I think I am forced to use `content-type: multipart/form-data`

```
curl --request POST --url https://************************* --header 'Authorization: Bearer ********'  --header 'content-type: multipart/form-data; ' --form cluster_id=0717-035521-puny598 --form start_time=1534357800000 --form end_time=1534444199999 --form order=ASC --form limit=500
```

Now I want to call same API using InvokeHTTP processor (NiFi). So I configured it as follows. But I am not able to do a successful call. (it is not a proxy issue).

[image]

[image]

Following is how I am creating POST body (by FF)

[image]

I have tried replacing "enter" by \r\n etc, or changing body  as `name1=val1&name2=val2&....` etc. nothing worked.

This is the response I am getting.

[[image: enter image description here]]

I am able to run CURL (shell, from same server where Nifi is running). Also I am able to access url via postman.

[[image: enter image description here]]

Comment: fixed image display

Comment: What does "nothing worked" mean? Are there errors thrown? Is the HTTP request made? Do you get a response? Can you point the processor at a local HTTP server to observe the request and compare it with the `curl` command you are issuing?

Comment: If the remote endpoint is HTTPS, you'll need to provide a `StandardSSLContextService` implementation in the *SSL Context Service* property of the `InvokeHTTP` processor. You should configure the truststore properties with the JVM `cacerts` file, and the default password is `changeit`.

Comment: @Andy : yes, I am getting response. Its 500. Server is saying request body is malformed. also CURL and POSTMAN works. Also I doubt it is to do with https, as I am able to call other URLs/APIs to same provider, and all thr URLs are https.  My doubt is how Nifi is sending form multipart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, it worked. flow is somewhat like this.

`GenerateFlowFile->UpdateAttribute->AttributesToJSON->InvokeHTTP`

Only change, I made to InvokeHTTP. reverted content-type back to ${mime.type}.

Comment: I have a similar issue... Where did you set boundary? Did u use multipart/form-data? What did you configure in update attributes?

Comment: Would also appreciate more info please

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this for a few hours.  I've got a backend API that has

`ResponseEntity<ByteArrayResource> post (@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file)` and a NiFi processor that sends XLSX data to this.  I was getting the same issue... The key for me were the bottom two properties:

FlowFile Form Data Name -> file (this is the name of the variable in the API call)

Set Flowfile Form Data File Name -> true